# Can I connect my electro acoustic guitar to a subwoofer?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

Newbie here
[image]

I have an electro acoustic guitar with this preamp equilizer inserted in it (don’t really know what it is). Can I plug my guitar directly in a subwoofer (I have a 2x1 logitech sound system with 2 speakers and a sub)?

I asked this because I plugged it in and I don’t hear anything through the speakers. Socket and cable working cause when I press the battery check on the preamp the sub does a loud sound

Answer (score 3):

In short, probably not.

The guitar needs to be plugged into an amp, not directly to a speaker.

Preferably a guitar amp, not a hifi, which will not like it at all.

Should you get that far, plugged into just a sub you will only hear frequencies below about 60Hz, which other than some body thumps is likely below any useful sound a guitar can produce.